# When the page changes, what can trigger loading all store states?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs5, ngrx

I am using **ngrx/store**, **ngrx/effects**, and **ngrx/router**.

My effects are like this:

```
 @Effect() loadOneProduct$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(LOAD_ONE_PRODUCT)
    .switchMap(() => this.productService.loadOneProduct())
    .map(oneProduct => ({ type: LOAD_ONE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS, payload: oneProduct }));

 @Effect() loadOneWorker$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(LOAD_ONE_WORKER)
    .switchMap(() => this.workerService.loadOneWorker())
    .map(oneWorker => ({ type: LOAD_ONE_WORKER_SUCCESS, payload: oneWorker }));
```

In the beginning, the store state is like this:

```
{
  company: { name: 'Google' },
  products: {},
  workers: {}
}
```

1) After running `this.store.dispatch({ type: LOAD_ONE_PRODUCT });`, it becomes like this:

```
{
  company: { name: 'Google' },
  products: {
    oneProduct: {
      label: 'Phone'
    } 
  },
  workers: {}
}
```

2) After running `this.store.dispatch({ type: LOAD_ONE_WORKER });`, it becomes like this:

```
{
  company: { name: 'Google' },
  products: {
    oneProduct: {
      label: 'Phone'
    } 
  },
  workers: {
    oneWorker: {
      name: 'Tom'
    } 
  },
}
```

3) Next when I go to another PAGE,

```
{{store|async|json}}

ngOnInit()
{
   this.subscription = this.store
      .select(x => x.products && x.products.oneProduct)
      .subscribe(oneProduct => {
        // Got undefined here. I suppose I can get the latest value from the store
        console.log(oneProduct);
      });

    // Everything will become correct if I `dispatch` any action
    // And I created a action called TEST, no reducer for it, which means won't change store state, also works
}
```

And now `{{store|async|json}}` shows:

```
{
  company: { name: 'Google' },
  products: {},
  workers: {}
}
```

All my states goes back to the initial state. Not only `products` disappears, but also `workers` disappears. (NOTE: `workers` also disappears.)

**(However, in Chrome Extention Redux Tools, the state tree shows correct all the time.)**

If I add a button and manually use ChangeDetectorRef, do `this._cdRef.detectChanges();`, `{{store|async|json}}` still shows initial state. (So seems not related with zone)

However, if I dispatch some actions after, both `products` and `workers` will come back to the state. And `{{store|async|json}}` shows correctly too.

Since in Chrome Extention Redux Tools, the state tree shows correct all the time. So I guess it just does not load correctly. My question is when the page changes, what can trigger loading all store states? Thanks

Comment: Hot / cold observable? When you subscribe you get the initial value?

Comment: @DerekKite yeah, I got initial value which is `undefined`. Actually my whole store state goes to initial state at that moment.

Comment: Does not the effects function changed the observable loadOneProduct$ as opposed to the state? In the example app the last map call dispatches to LOAD_ONE_WORKER_SUCCESS which then in the reducer updates the state. Maybe the state isn't being modified. BTW, i really don't know, I'm figuring this stuff out myself.

Comment: I notice that the commented out line of code in the last section references `_store`, but you reference `store` in the uncommented out section. Did you make a typo?

Comment: @slmyers yeah a typo, just corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an Angular 2 issue:

Check https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/171

and fixed by

https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/a46437c57d0c6a2cffb8256cc9e4f1ab69fef4ea